# Hyper-v replication assistance

Tags: hyper-v

I have a new Windows Hyper-V Server 2016 (the free one) under workgroup and would like to make one of the VMs replicating into another Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V

For the Wind 2012 I managed to generate certificates  but for the Win 2016 as it works powershell or simple cmd, I can't generate certificate which will be accepted...can you please assist?

Comment: It would be helpful to describe in more detail what you have tried so far and what errors/problems you are experiencing in trying to get it to work.

Comment: The above comment is right, if you provide more info it's easier to help.
But you can avoid a bunch of problems if you stay away from makecert.exe and use Powershell, see http://blog.fedenko.info/2016/06/hyper-v-replica-with-self-signed.html